# It is possible to launch Chrome(Chromium) from OpenSolaris?

Tags: google-chrome, opensolaris, chromium

It is possible to launch Chrome(Chromium) from OpenSolaris? Who succeed to launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [Google Chromium project](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30101) on google code there seems to be some talk about this.

But sadly the most recent comments are up to May 05, 2010 and are still asking if there is any progress. There seems to be some people writing patches for it. But it does not appear to be available as of now.

That link may be a good place to keep an eye on for updates.

And finally the last part of your question

> "Who turned?"

This is extremely vague, what do you mean by this.

Comment: i mean that, what mean google translate from russian

Comment: i mean who succeed to launch